# Regex to match all closing HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex

For some reason, I need to remove all closing HTML tags from a string in PHP, so I need a Regular Expression to match all closing HTML Tags. I'm extremely unexperienced with Regular Expressions, so I tried using `/\<\\.*\>/g` and  `/<\\.*>/g`, but that didn't work. What should I use instead?

Please note that I only want to match closing HTML tags. Opening HTML Tags should remain untouched. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason that did not work is because you were doing a `greedy` match.  If you did that with a `lazy` match and fixed the slash direction, it would work fine.  Adding a `?` after, at least in this case, makes it `lazy`.  You may want to look into why [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
</.+?>
```

or

```
/<\/.+?>/
```

That will do.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/zW9wU8)

Answer (score 3):

Matching HTML with a regex is not a good idea, but if you have to, you can use

```
/<\/[^<>]*>/g
```

**Explanation:**

```
</     # Match </
[^<>]* # Match any number of characters except angle brackets
>      # Match >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<\/[\w^_]*>/
```

because u dont want to match  ?.=- and _ in tag.